# Send JSON data with logger command

Tags: command-line, syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to use (Ubuntu) logger command to send data to Logstash. I want the data to contain JSON structured data, like:

```
logger -p syslog.warn "{"user":"admin", "password":"admin"}}"
```

I remember once I read something about @eee somewhere but I can't found that page again, kind of:

```
logger -p syslog.warn @eee"{"user":"admin", "password":"admin"}}
```

How can I send JSON data with logger command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the eee stuff, but you just need to change your command a little bit (escaping the quotation marks):

`logger -p syslog.warn {\"user\":\"admin\", \"password\":\"admin\"}`

Meanwhile, run tailf to watch the syslog

```
$ tailf /var/log/syslog
Jan 12 18:25:48 laptop ubuntu: {"user":"admin", "password":"admin"}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t enclosing the json part in single quotes be simpler? `logger -p syslog.warn '{"user":"admin", "password":"admin"}'`